# Change Window.Content value in UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have one window and some userControls. When Window loaded, one of UserControls programicaly Hosted in Window.Content. Suppose, userControls have buttons that when clicked by user this Current UserControl Removed from window.Content and destoryed  and another userControl added to parent Window.Content. I used Parent like this:

```
(Parent as Window).Content =  new MyUserControl;
```

But after once changing parent userControl, result of Parent return null and previous userConrol did not destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Just created the attached sample to test what you are trying to do. Kindly provide some more detail about the code you have. Attached sample does exactly what you said without any null references.

[Sample](http://www.mediafire.com/?1fds82s3bgcu6k6)